# How can I get the amount of available memory portably across distributions?

Tags: linux, memory, meminfo

The standard files/tools that report memory seem to have different formats on different Linux distributions. For example, on Arch and Ubuntu.

- Arch

  ```
  $ free
                total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
  Mem:        8169312     3870392     2648348       97884     1650572     4110336
  Swap:      16777212      389588    16387624


  $ head /proc/meminfo 
  MemTotal:        8169312 kB
  MemFree:         2625668 kB
  MemAvailable:    4088520 kB
  Buffers:          239688 kB
  Cached:          1224520 kB
  SwapCached:        17452 kB
  Active:          4074548 kB
  Inactive:        1035716 kB
  Active(anon):    3247948 kB
  Inactive(anon):   497684 kB
  ```
- Ubuntu

  ```
  $ free
               total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
  Mem:      80642828   69076080   11566748    3063796     150688   58358264
  -/+ buffers/cache:   10567128   70075700
  Swap:     20971516    5828472   15143044


  $ head /proc/meminfo 
  MemTotal:       80642828 kB
  MemFree:        11565936 kB
  Buffers:          150688 kB
  Cached:         58358264 kB
  SwapCached:      2173912 kB
  Active:         27305364 kB
  Inactive:       40004480 kB
  Active(anon):    7584320 kB
  Inactive(anon):  4280400 kB
  Active(file):   19721044 kB
  ```

So, how can I portably (across Linux distros only) and reliably get the amount of memory—excluding swap—that is available for my software to use at a particular time? Presumably that's what's shown as "available" and "MemAvailable" in the output of `free` and `cat /proc/meminfo` in Arch but how do I get the same in Ubuntu or another distribution?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`MemAvailable` is included in `/proc/meminfo` since version 3.14 of the kernel; it was added by [commit 34e431b0a](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=34e431b0a). That's the determining factor in the output variations you show. The commit message indicates how to estimate available memory without `MemAvailable`:

> Currently, the amount of memory that is available for a new workload, without pushing the system into swap, can be estimated from `MemFree`, `Active(file)`, `Inactive(file)`, and `SReclaimable`, as well as the "low" watermarks from `/proc/zoneinfo`.

The low watermarks are the level beneath which the system will swap. So in the absence of `MemAvailable` you can at least add up the values given for `MemFree`, `Active(file)`, `Inactive(file)` and `SReclaimable` (whichever are present in `/proc/meminfo`), and subtract the low watermarks from `/proc/zoneinfo`. The latter also lists the number of free pages per zone, that might be useful as a comparison...

The complete algorithm is given in the patch to `meminfo.c` and seems reasonably easy to adapt:

- sum the low watermarks across all zones;
- take the identified free memory (`MemFree`);
- subtract the low watermark (we need to avoid touching that to avoid swapping);
- add the amount of memory we can use from the page cache (sum of `Active(file)` and `Inactive(file)`): that's the amount of memory used by the page cache, minus either half the page cache, or the low watermark, whichever is smaller;
- add the amount of memory we can reclaim (`SReclaimable`), following the same algorithm.

So, putting all this together, you can get the memory available for a new process with:

```
awk -v low=$(grep low /proc/zoneinfo | awk '{k+=$2}END{print k}') \
 '{a[$1]=$2}
  END{ 
   print a["MemFree:"]+a["Active(file):"]+a["Inactive(file):"]+a["SReclaimable:"]-(12*low); 
  }' /proc/meminfo
```

Comment: Ah, good, so at least it should be portable across the same kernel version. That's something. I'm testing your suggestion with `awk -v low=$(grep low /proc/zoneinfo | awk '{k+=$2}END{print k}') '{a[$1]=$2}END{m=a["MemFree:"]+a["Active(file):"]+a["Inactive(file):"]+a["SReclaimable:"]; print a["MemAvailable:"],m-low}' /proc/meminfo` which should give me the same number printed twice. However, the second number (my understanding of the algorithm you suggest) is higher than the `MemAvailable` shown in `/proc/meminfo`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `/proc/zoneinfo` counts pages, which are mostly 4KB in size on `amd64`; you're also missing the extra safety added to the page cache and the reclaimable memory. Simplifying the latter, we can subtract the low watermark three times, so `m-12*low` (3 × 4KB) gives the correct result on my system. (This simplification underestimates available memory if the page cache or reclaimable memory is smaller than twice the low watermark, but you wouldn't want to use much memory in that situation anyway so that seems to be a reasonable compromise.)

Comment: @StephenKitt how would you go about calculating it for older kernels that don't have either `(file)` entires or the `SReclaimable` entry? On an older centos box with kernel v 2.6.18-348.16.1.el5xen (per `uname -r`) this is the output I get: http://pastebin.com/iFWiM1kX . Your calculation only pulls the `MemFree` part

Comment: @Mitch I don't know, I'm not sure the information available from your old kernel is sufficient to determine the available memory (before swapping) accurately.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who contributed to this thread, it is a great reference. The calculation of MemAvailable has been adjusted slightly in Linux 4.5. However the new MemAvailable calculation should always be slightly higher than (or maybe the same as) the old one, so it should be safe to use the old calculation in all cases.  https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/issues/42

Comment: Beautiful answer by @Stephen and it works nice.

I know it is a late question, but can somebody please help me in understanding the significance of 12*LOW. (So I read that the simplification is 4kb*3). I didn't understand the multiple of 3.

What are these "extra safety added to the page cache and the reclaimable memory" ?

Comment: @Vipin the low watermark comes into play three times: once as the low watermark in the zones directly, once as the minimal value for the memory kept in the page cache (the extra safety added to the page cache, the second-last bullet point in the answer), and once as the minimal value for the reclaimable pages (the extra safety added to the reclaimable memory, the last bullet point in the answer). Subtracting it three times thus gives a good approximation.

Answer (score 7):

While Stephen's answer is perfectly sufficient and errs on the side of caution, I decided to write up the full logic including the minimum comparisons.  Information is first read from /proc/meminfo and stored in a variable so that memory details are consistent.

```
LOW_WATERMARK=$(awk '$1 == "low" {LOW_WATERMARK += $2} END {print LOW_WATERMARK * 4096}' /proc/zoneinfo)

MEMINFO=$(</proc/meminfo)

MEMINFO_MEMFREE=$(echo "${MEMINFO}" | awk '$1 == "MemFree:" {print $2 * 1024}')
MEMINFO_FILE=$(echo "${MEMINFO}" | awk '{MEMINFO[$1]=$2} END {print (MEMINFO["Active(file):"] + MEMINFO["Inactive(file):"]) * 1024}')
MEMINFO_SRECLAIMABLE=$(echo "${MEMINFO}" | awk '$1 == "SReclaimable:" {print $2 * 1024}')

MEMINFO_MEMAVAILABLE=$((
  MEMINFO_MEMFREE - LOW_WATERMARK
  + MEMINFO_FILE - ((MEMINFO_FILE/2) < LOW_WATERMARK ? (MEMINFO_FILE/2) : LOW_WATERMARK)
  + MEMINFO_SRECLAIMABLE - ((MEMINFO_SRECLAIMABLE/2) < LOW_WATERMARK ? (MEMINFO_SRECLAIMABLE/2) : LOW_WATERMARK)
))

if [[ "${MEMINFO_MEMAVAILABLE}" -le 0 ]]
then
  MEMINFO_MEMAVAILABLE=0
fi
```

Result stored in variable is in bytes.

Comment: While this answer implements the computation in the commit 34e431b0a, Stephen Kitt's answer provided more accurate estimate on 2 machines out of 5 I tested. On all 5 machines, both answer gave larger estimates than MemAvailable read directly from /proc/meminfo. Probably a safer way is to obtain the smaller between the 2, and multiply by 0.95 or so.