# Meaning of "available" field in "free -m" command

Tags: linux, centos

I am using Linux CentOS 7.2 version.

I have searched details about this but can't found any useful information.

What is this about?

Answer (score 4):

From [`free(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/free.1.html):

> Estimation of how much memory is available for starting new
>                 applications, without swapping. Unlike the data provided by
>                 the **cache** or **free** fields, this field takes into account page
>                 cache and also that not all reclaimable memory slabs will be
>                 reclaimed due to items being in use (`MemAvailable` in
>                 `/proc/meminfo`, available on kernels 3.14, emulated on kernels
>                 2.6.27+, otherwise the same as `free`)

It reports the amount of physical memory that's available, *i.e.* that can be used without causing the system to start swapping. [How can I get the amount of available memory portably across distributions?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/261247/86440) has more information.

Comment: Thanks for infomation but I need to how to calculate "available" options from ram and whether relating  buffer and cache memoryand etc ?

Comment: @BabakMammadov, could you [edit your question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/326833/edit) to explain exactly what information you're looking for then? Did you see the [linked question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/261247/86440)? It explains the algorithm used to calculate the available memory.

Comment: Thanks. Does "available" consist of exactly "free" and part of "buffer/cache"? Which part of "buffer/cache" does "available" not consist of?

Comment: @Tim the linked question details exactly how “available” is calculated.

Comment: "Estimation of how much memory is available for starting new **applications**, without swapping. "  Does it mean "Estimation of how much memory is available for starting new **processes**, without swapping." instead of existing processes calling execve() to run new applications?

Comment: @Tim what distinction are you trying to make?

Comment: I remember execve() will first deallocate the original memory for the old program and then allocate new memory for the new program. So do the deallocated memory for the old program become part of "available"?

Comment: @Tim OK, but generally `execve` is called after a `fork`, so it frees memory which was just allocated. If you start a new process (without replacing an existing process), the memory you have available to do so is estimated by `MemAvailable`.