# How shall I understand the output of free?

Tags: linux, memory

I have read [What do the "buff/cache" and "avail mem" fields in top mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/390518/what-do-the-buff-cache-and-avail-mem-fields-in-top-mean)
and 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/770108/what-do-the-changes-in-free-output-from-14-04-to-16-04-mean. But still have questions.

```
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.7G        5.3G        268M        620M        2.1G        1.5G
Swap:           14G        874M         14G
```

Does "used" already include "shared"?

Can "available" be determined from other columns?

Why does "available" not equal to sum of "free" and "buff/cache"?

I thought that "buff/cache" is actually available to be used by starting a new process, so why is "available" smaller than "buff/cache"?

What columns does "total - used" (2.4G) consist of? Why isn't it the same as "available"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [the `free` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/free.1.html) for some answers; in particular:

> **used**   Used memory (calculated as **total** - **free** - **buffers** - **cache**)

[The `proc` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) is also worth reading (look at the `/proc/meminfo` description).

Addressing your questions:

> Does "used" already include "shared"?

Yes.

> Can "available" be determined from other columns?

No; see [Meaning of "available" field in "free -m" command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/326833/86440) and [How can I get the amount of available memory portably across distributions?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/261247/86440) for the (gory) details.

> Why does "available" not equal to sum of "free" and "buff/cache"?

See above. It indicates the amount of memory which can be used without swapping; “buff/cache” includes memory which can’t immediately be reclaimed, and is therefore not available.

> I thought that "buff/cache" is actually available to be used by starting a new process, so why is "available" smaller than "buff/cache"?

See above.

> What columns does "total - used" (2.4G) consist of? Why isn't it the same as "available"?

See above.

Comment: Thanks. Do "total,  free,   used,  buff/cache,  avail mem" in `top` output mean the same as in `free` output?

Comment: Yes, they mean the same.

Comment: Does "used" memory include kernel memory (which is also called "Wired memory" if I am correct)? I guess no, but kernel memory is mapped to the virtual address space of each process.

Comment: “used” includes some kernel allocations IIRC; the kernel binary isn’t accounted for there, it simply doesn’t appear in the total memory, but total memory doesn’t decrease when the kernel allocates more memory. The values we’re discussing here relate to physical memory, not the address space.

Comment: Thanks. (1) "“used” includes some kernel allocations". Are those kernel allocation in user space or kernel space? What are they used for?   (2) "the kernel binary isn’t accounted for there". so does the memory allocated for kernel data structures?

Comment: They’re used any time the kernel needs memory: `kmalloc` allocations, page caches, etc. Again, we’re discussing physical memory, so where they happen in the address space isn’t particularly relevant (but the kernel maps them in its own address space).