# Why the numbers of "free" don't add up?

Tags: linux, memory, free

This is a side question when I try to figure out why my Ubuntu18.04 server keeps using up memory and mysql gets killed from time to time.

```
         total      used      free    shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:      3.9G      1.2G      142M      2.0G        2.5G        346M
Swap:     511M      510M      2.0M
```

[image]

The above is the result of running "free" command.
I've been trying to figure out how the numbers can be added up to the total(3.9g) to no avail.
Can someone explain please?

Comment: https://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How shall I understand the output of free?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/478443)