# What does top KiB Mem percent data mean?

Tags: top

When I use top, the memory data is displayed in the overview area as follows：

```
KiB Mem : 16092836 total,   143168 free, 11005184 used,  4944484 buff/cache
```

Then I use m (interactive command) to switch the memory data display mode：

```
KiB Mem : 88.7/16092836 [|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||         ]
```

My question is: the result of `100*used/total` is `68.3856`, how was the `88.7` calculated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>The percentage is equivalent to `100*used/total`, as you imagined.</del>

The percentage is `100*(1-available/total)`, confusingly different from `100*used/total`.

Here, "available" means the same as shown in `free`.

Related threads:

- [Meaning of "available" field in "free -m" command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/326833/meaning-of-available-field-in-free-m-command)
- [How shall I understand the output of free?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478443/how-shall-i-understand-the-output-of-free?noredirect=1&lq=1)

## Reference manual

The behavior is [documented in the reference manual](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/blob/d4ecd5cb3575928000eb7dc796626c92ff3d380b/man/top.1#L596).

> In the alternate memory display modes, two abbreviated summary lines are
> shown consisting of these elements:
>
> ```
>                a    b          c
>     GiB Mem : 18.7/15.738   [ ... ]
>     GiB Swap:  0.0/7.999    [ ... ]
> ```
>
> Where: a) is the percentage used; b) is the total available; and c) > is
> one of two visual graphs of those representations.
>
> In the case of physical memory, the percentage represents the **total**
> minus the estimated **avail** noted above. The `Mem' graph itself is
> divided between the non-cached portion of **used** and any remaining
> memory not otherwise accounted for by **avail**. See topic 4b. SUMMARY
> AREA Commands and the `m' command for additional information on that
> special 4-way toggle.

## Source code of `top`

As of now, it can be verified by investigating the source code.

### [Data passed to the graph view](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/blob/d4ecd5cb3575928000eb7dc796626c92ff3d380b/src/top/top.c#L6602)

```c
#ifdef MEMGRAPH_OLD
      my_misc = my_qued;
#else
      my_misc = MEM_VAL(mem_TOT) - MEM_VAL(mem_AVL) - my_used;
#endif
      Graph_mems->total = MEM_VAL(mem_TOT);
      Graph_mems->part1 = my_used;
      Graph_mems->part2 = my_misc;
```

### [Calculation in the graph view](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/blob/d4ecd5cb3575928000eb7dc796626c92ff3d380b/src/top/top.c#L6271)

```c
   if (these->total > 0)
      scale = 100.0 / these->total;
   rx.pcnt_one = scale * these->part1;
   rx.pcnt_two = scale * these->part2;
   if (rx.pcnt_one + rx.pcnt_two > 100.0 || rx.pcnt_two < 0)
      rx.pcnt_two = 0;
   rx.pcnt_tot = rx.pcnt_one + rx.pcnt_two;
```

### [Data passed to the default view](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/blob/d4ecd5cb3575928000eb7dc796626c92ff3d380b/src/top/top.c#L6643)

```c
      prT(bfT(0), mkM(MEM_VAL(mem_TOT))); prT(bfT(1), mkM(MEM_VAL(mem_FRE)));
      prT(bfT(2), mkM(MEM_VAL(mem_USE))); prT(bfT(3), mkM(my_qued));
      prT(bfT(4), mkM(MEM_VAL(swp_TOT))); prT(bfT(5), mkM(MEM_VAL(swp_FRE)));
      prT(bfT(6), mkM(MEM_VAL(swp_USE))); prT(bfT(7), mkM(MEM_VAL(mem_AVL)));

      snprintf(row, sizeof(row), N_unq(MEMORY_line1_fmt)
         , scT(label), N_txt(WORD_abv_mem_txt), bfT(0), bfT(1), bfT(2), bfT(3));
      Msg_row += sum_see(row, mem2UP);
```

## On the reported inconsistency

- Did you check if your snapshots that you're matching are produced at the same system state? If printed at the same time, the used memory might be just 88.7% even in the default view.
- What is the version of your `top`? The current behavior of memory window has been introduced in [3.3.10](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/commit/fd71717b9b760c988898f5eb0d1459f0b04cc739).
- Which platform are you running it on? <del>It seems there are some flags that can change the data passed to graph.</del>

---

Corrected after further information and reveiw.

Comment: (1) I'm pretty sure both data were captured at the same time  
(2) my `top` version is `procps-ng version 3.3.10`  
(3) the platform is `CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core) `