# What do the "buff/cache" and "avail mem" fields in top mean?

Tags: linux, memory, top

Within the output of top, there are two fields, marked "buff/cache" and "avail Mem" in the memory and swap usage lines:

[image]

What do these two fields mean?

I've tried Googling them, but the results only bring up generic articles on top, and they don't explain what these fields signify.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

`top`’s manpage doesn’t describe the fields, but [`free`’s](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/free.1.html) does:

> **buffers**
>
> Memory used by kernel buffers (`Buffers` in `/proc/meminfo`)
>
> **cache**
>
> Memory used by the page cache and slabs (`Cached` and
> `SReclaimable` in `/proc/meminfo`)
>
> **buff/cache**
>
> Sum of buffers and cache
>
> **available**
>
> Estimation of how much memory is available for starting new
> applications, without swapping. Unlike the data provided by
> the cache or free fields, this field takes into account page
> cache and also that not all reclaimable memory slabs will be
> reclaimed due to items being in use (`MemAvailable` in
> `/proc/meminfo`, available on kernels 3.14, emulated on kernels
> 2.6.27+, otherwise the same as free)

Basically, “buff/cache” counts memory used for data that’s on disk or should end up there soon, and as a result is potentially usable (the corresponding memory can be made available immediately, if it hasn’t been modified since it was read, or given enough time, if it has); “available” measures the amount of memory which can be allocated and used without causing more swapping (see [How can I get the amount of available memory portably across distributions?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/261247/86440) for a lot more detail on that).

Answer (score 26):

Just to clarify a bit, **buffers** refers to data that is being **written** -- that memory cannot be reclaimed until the write is complete.

**Cache** refers to data that has been **read** -- it is kept around in case it needs to be read again, but can be immediately reclaimed since it can always be re-read from disk.

Comment: That's not really what it means here.  `/proc/meminfo` has a field for `Writeback` specifically.  There is a separate field `Buffers`, and that is what is shown as `buffers` in `free -w`.  A common reason for `Buffers` memory usage is shown here: "[30% of RAM is “buffers”. What is it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/440558/30-of-ram-is-buffers-what-is-it)"

Comment: From this (https://access.redhat.com/solutions/406773) I take it that Writeback is that portion of Buffers that has not yet been written to disk.  Or are you saying something else?

Comment: That description would be misleading. `Buffers` is (now) a part of the page cache; it is not counted in `Cached`, but it is counted as part of `Active(file) + Inactive(file)`.  See comments on Stephen Kitt's answer.  `Dirty` is the part of the page cache which has been written to, and so eventually needs writing back to disk.  [`Writeback` does not include `Dirty`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/481694/in-proc-meminfo-does-dirty-include-or-exclude-writeback/481695).  Therefore, `Writeback` is not a portion of the value of `Buffers`.

Comment: What `Buffers` actually means is the page cache associated with the block device.  Some filesystems use this internally; others don't use it at all.  /goes to fixup my answer on the "30% of my RAM is buffers" question.

Answer (score 19):

**The canonical source of this information is** [/usr/src/linux/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt;hb=HEAD#l451)

> **Buffers**: Relatively temporary storage for raw disk blocks shouldn't
>   get tremendously large (20MB or so) 
>   **Cached**: in-memory cache for files
>   read from the disk (the page cache).  Doesn't include SwapCached.

**You can also find some more details [here](https://linux-mm.org/Low_On_Memory).**

> The Linux Page Cache ("**Cached**:" from meminfo ) is the largest single
>   consumer of RAM on most systems. Any time you do a read() from a file
>   on disk, that data is read into memory, and goes into the page
>   cache(1.).
>   The buffer cache ("**Buffers**:" in meminfo) is a close
>   relative to the dentry/inode caches.

**Or analysis the source code like [this](http://linuxperf.com/?p=32).**

The amount of `buffers` is the return value of function `nr_blockdev_pages(void)`

```
long nr_blockdev_pages(void)
{
        struct block_device *bdev;
        long ret = 0;
        spin_lock(&bdev_lock);
        list_for_each_entry(bdev, &all_bdevs, bd_list) {
                ret += bdev->bd_inode->i_mapping->nrpages;
        }
        spin_unlock(&bdev_lock);
        return ret;
}
```

The amount of `cached`:

```
global_page_state(NR_FILE_PAGES) – total_swapcache_pages – i.bufferram
```