# In /proc/meminfo, does Dirty include or exclude Writeback?

Tags: linux-kernel, memory, proc, cache

> `Dirty` %lu - Memory which is waiting to get written back to the disk.
>
> `Writeback` %lu - Memory which is actively being written back to the disk.
>
> -- [man proc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)

Does `Dirty` include `Writeback`?  Or is it excluded?

My kernel version is 4.18.16-200.fc28.x86_64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“Dirty” and “Writeback” are separate stats and page states; for proof of this, see for example [`node_dirty_ok`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/mm/page-writeback.c?id=dad4f140edaa3f6bb452b6913d41af1ffd672e45#n495):

```
nr_pages += node_page_state(pgdat, NR_FILE_DIRTY);
nr_pages += node_page_state(pgdat, NR_UNSTABLE_NFS);
nr_pages += node_page_state(pgdat, NR_WRITEBACK);

return nr_pages <= limit;
```

If one included the other, that would be taken into account here.

`/proc/meminfo` [doesn’t process the corresponding values either](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/proc/meminfo.c?id=61f94e18de94f79abaad3bb83549ff78923ac785#n91):

```
show_val_kb(m, "Dirty:          ",
        global_node_page_state(NR_FILE_DIRTY));
show_val_kb(m, "Writeback:      ",
        global_node_page_state(NR_WRITEBACK));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `Dirty` excludes `Writeback`.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=~/X.img bs=1M count=1 ; sync & for i in 1 2 3; do grep -E '^(Dirty:|Writeback:|MemFree:|Cached:)' /proc/meminfo ; done
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1048576 bytes (1.0 MB, 1.0 MiB) copied, 0.00316564 s, 331 MB/s
[1] 13140
MemFree:         1461832 kB
Cached:          1475188 kB
Dirty:               132 kB
Writeback:          1032 kB
...
```

(Although this is only proof if `/proc/meminfo` is guaranteed 100% consistent).