# Memory immediately available in Linux memory management system

Tags: linux-kernel, memory, free

This is the output of `free -h` command on my `Ubuntu 18.04` laptop:

```
$ free -hg
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            11G        4,2G        3,4G        801M        4,0G        6,3G
Swap:           11G          0B         11G
```

From what I understand after a short research using mostly stackexchange sites (e.g. [this elaboration](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867068/what-is-available-memory-while-using-free-command)), the main difference between `free` and `available` memory is that `free` is actually `free` and `available` **can** become `free` if the need arises.

What is the process via which the `available` memory is allocated to a task that creates the relevant need?

Does flushing dirty pages and freeing up `cache` (to allocate the memory freed up to a process that requires it) constitute part of such a process?

In such a case I assume `available` should always be > `cache`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[It’s a bit more complicated than that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/261252/86440). Available memory is memory which is *immediately* reclaimable, *i.e.* can be re-purposed without losing data, minus certain thresholds below which the system swaps. This doesn’t include dirty pages, since they need to be written out, and that can take a lot of time.

See the above link for details. In particular, the existence of thresholds, and the fact that “buff/cache” includes dirty pages, means that there is no guarantee that the available memory is larger than the amount given under “buff/cache”.

Comment: However can't the mmanagement module free memory from inactive(file), thus by flushing cache to hard disk? "inactive :The amount of inactive memory (in KB), or memory that has not been used for a while and is eligible to be swapped to disk." (from: https://bit.ly/2OTM4VW)

Comment: “Inactive(file)” represents the inactive part of the page cache, *i.e.* file-backed memory which hasn’t been used recently. It isn’t dirty, so it can be discarded at any time (the data is stored elsewhere already).